# Focus on the first element of the list view control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list view control in my xaml file. I'm having a textblock and a dropdown field inside the list view. The data is coming from the database. I want the focus to be on the first dropdown. But the focus is not coming there. If I press tab then only the focus is coming. My list view is inside a groupbox.

Comment: Does listview has ItemsSource, or you fill it in code behind?

Comment: I'm using a itemsource in view model to fill the values.

Answer (score 0):

if your `ComboBox`'s name was "_drop" then I hope these two line can help you:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_drop"
    SelectedIndex="0"
    TabIndex="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in XAML, however you could pull out the element from the items control's children manually and call `Focus()` on it from your code.